# Functional PDF Testing (Automate Testing of PDF Content)

Tags: pdf, automation, automated-tests, watin, watij

I am working on an application where I am writing some automation framework for testing a web application.  I am using Watij / Watin for the framework, but have run into a problem with verifying the PDFs generated have the correct content.

I know I can use IText or a native PDF library to load up the PDF, but I am wondering if there is already an existing framework dedicated to testing PDF file content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's an interesting problem, but thankfully like most out there, there's someone who has done it before you.

Take a look at http://jpdfunit.sourceforge.net/references/jpdfunit_aShortIntroduction.pdf for information on a PDF testing framework called JPdfUnit.

The program homepage is at http://jpdfunit.sourceforge.net/.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simple [PDF Automation](http://autoitsourcecode.blogspot.com/2013/05/pdf-automation-using-autoit.html) to read text from PDF document.